# Why are 008 and 009 invalid keys for Python dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

Why is it that I can't have 008 or 009 be keys for a Python dict, but 001-007 are fine?
Example:

```
some_dict = {
    001: "spam",
    002: "eggs",
    003: "foo",
    004: "bar",
    008: "anything", # Throws a SyntaxError
    009: "nothing"   # Throws a SyntaxError
    }
```

**Update**: Problem solved. I wasn't aware that starting a literal with a zero made it octal. That seems really odd. Why zero?

Comment: Why in Python?  Historical precendent (C did it).  I have no idea why it was in C, because I agree that it's pretty silly.

Comment: yeah, we're stuck with it.  If you have to have the zeros, make them strings instead.  The dictionary will work fine.

Comment: Octal literals used to be represented with an "o" (i.e. o73). I don't know why it was changed to a zero (0) in C-type languages. Hexadecimal numbers (base 16) have been represented with an x (or 0x) prefix or an 'h' suffix (0x2AE, 2AEh). And some languages have used the prefix 'b' to represent binary numbers.

Comment: As bad as using a leading zero to indicate an octal number is, JavaScript has the *insane* behavior of automatically ignoring the fact that a number should be octal if it has any non-octal digits. So in JavaScript, 077 represents 63 decimal while 078 represents 78 decimal. The worst of both worlds..

Comment: Robert: You are asking why was it changed almost 40 years ago to zero. The real question is why do newer languages keep doing it?

Comment: The only language that does this in a sane manner is Ada (no, really!).  16#0c7fff#, 2#0011_0100#, 8#0664#, etc.

Comment: Jacob, doesn't Python 3.0 have a decent way too? Like, 0d9623, 0x1F6A, and 0o756? Sure, it isn't as clear as Ada, but it is certainly better than the current state.

Comment: I did a little digging and it looks like the usage of a leading digit goes back at least as far as BCPL. The original BCPL (ca.1967) used a leading 8. Other BCPL versions used a leading # for octal and #x for hex or even a trailing 'B' for octal. ALGOL, however, only included decimal literals AFAICT.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In python and some other languages, if you start a number with a 0, the number is interpreted as being in octal (base 8), where only 0-7 are valid digits.  You'll have to change your code to this:

```
some_dict = { 
    1: "spam",
    2: "eggs",
    3: "foo",
    4: "bar",
    8: "anything",
    9: "nothing" }
```

Or if the leading zeros are really important, use strings for the keys.

Comment: I really, really wish that K&R hadn't come up with that convention for octal (I assume it was them)...

Comment: @Michael - it looks like K&R may have chosen '0' but the prefix form for octal seems to predate them. I traced it back to the original BCPL definition. They probably chose '0' as a nicety for the lexer.

Comment: It doesn't bother me all that much that it's a C convention.  What bothers me is that other C-like languages (not counting those designed to be directly compatible) copied it.  I hadn't realized the convention existed in Python.  Ick.

Answer (score 10):

Python takes 008 and 009 as octal numbers, therefore...invalid.

You can only go up to 007, then the next number would be 010 (8) then 011 (9).  Try it in a Python interpreter, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 8):

In Python (and many other languages), starting a number with **a leading "0"** indicates an **octal number** (base 8). Using this leading-zero notation is called an **octal literal**. Octal numbers go 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, etc. So **08 (in octal) is invalid**.

If you remove the leading zeros, your code will be fine:

```
some_dict = 
{ 
    1: "spam",
    2: "eggs",
    3: "foo",
    4: "bar",
    8: "anything",
    9: "nothing" 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

@DoxaLogos is right. It's not that they're invalid keys - they're invalid literals. If you tried to use them in any other context, you'd get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

That is because, when you start a number with a `0`, it is interpreted as an octal number. Since `008` and `009` are not octal numbers, it fails.

A `0` precedes an octal number so that you do not have to write `(127)₈`. From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#In_computers): *"Sometimes octal numbers are represented by preceding a value with a 0 (e.g. in Python 2.x or JavaScript 1.x - although it is now deprecated in both)."*